# How to use 3rd party react lib with React.Fragments in React 15

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, uicomponents, react-16

Here's my problem

Building a React Component Library in React 16.3 and using `React.Fragments`.

Sadly this needs to support a few different React sites including one which includes React `15.4.1`.

When trying to use a component which has `React.Fragment` even after babel, minification etc I get

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

Is there any way at all to support this use case without updating the old sites react version ?

Comment: can you show us a bit of code, of how are you using it?

Comment: btw I think React.Fragment was added in React 16, it is not available in <= 15.x

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style={{ display: 'contents' }}></span>
```

This works for me.